# Conditional Not Working as Expected.

Tags: conditionals

I have a  series of performance dates; let's say 5.

```
 {performance_date_one format="%l, %F %j, %Y; %g:%i %a"}
```

However,  after a date has passed, I want to gray the date out and remove the link, but I want to keep it on screen until all five performance are finished.

This code doesn't work. It prints two dates one grayed out the original date.

```
  {if performance_date_one}  
  {if "{expiration_date format='%U'}" < "{current_time format='%U'}"}
 <h5><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-calendar"></i> &nbsp;  
 {performance_date_one format="%l, %F %j, %Y; %g:%i %a"}</h5>{/if}

 <h5 class="color-gray-aaa"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-calendar"> 
 </i> &nbsp;{performance_date_one format="%l, %F %j, %Y; %g:%i %a"} <span class="label    
 label-default small">PAST</span></h5>{/if}
```

I am stuck, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to change the inner IF statement into one that has an ELSE clause.  So you get either the first  or the second - your logic currently gives two lines if the inner-if statement fires.  I think you want something like this...

`{if performance_date_one}

    {if "{expiration_date format='%U'}" < "{current_time format='%U'}"}
        <h5><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-calendar"></i> &nbsp; {performance_date_one format="%l, %F %j, %Y; %g:%i %a"}</h5>
    {if:else}
    <h5 class="color-gray-aaa"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-calendar"></i> &nbsp;{performance_date_one format="%l, %F %j, %Y; %g:%i %a"} <span class="label la bel-default small">PAST</span></h5>
    {/if}
{/if}`

HTH